# Coin toss using random numbers does not appear exactly random

Tags: java, random, coin-flipping

I wanted a random number generator to simulate a coin toss and here's what i did

```
public class CoinToss
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int num=(int)(1000*Math.random());
        if(num<500)
            System.out.println("H");
        else
            System.out.println("T");
    }
}
```

The results were discouraging as i got 16 Heads and 4 tails in 20 runs.
That does not **appear** to be random. Its possible but i want a general opinion if the program is correct ? Am i missing something mathematically ?

Comment: Try running it some more times. You may get better results.

Comment: 20 samples is meaningless mathematically speaking, tray again with a bigger sample (at least 10k)

Comment: Yeah, @Preuk is right. I just looped over your example with max_int and here's the result: H: 1073754033, T: 1073729614

Comment: Your initial problem is that you think the words "exactly random" are meaningful. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code a little and it seems to be random enough.

code:

```
    int h = 0;
    int t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int num = (int) (1000 * Math.random());
        if (num < 500) {
            h++;

        } else {
            t++;

        }
    }
    System.out.println("T:" + t);
    System.out.println("H:" + h);
```

output:

```
T:506
H:494
```

I guess this is the thing with randomness ^^

Answer (score 1):

20 runs is not a big enough sample size to assess how random it is. Think of it this way: if you did 4 runs and got 4 heads, you'd think, "Wow, that's not random at all." But in fact if you took 4 coins, and flipped them 16 times, you'd expect to get all 4 heads at least once. So if you do a small number of runs, and you get results that aren't equally divided between heads and tails, that doesn't mean it's not random.

Or look at it this way: if you wrote some code that just printed "Heads" then "Tails" then "Heads" and so on, you'd get exactly half heads and half tails. But that's not random at all! It's just a repeating pattern.

So the moral of the story is not to be surprised when random results look uneven over short runs. Try re-writing your code so that it counts how many heads and how many tails, and let it flip about a million or so, and see if you don't get about 500,000 each. It should be a little more or a little less, because random doesn't give you exact, but it should be closer.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be correct although you could implement it easier:

```
Random r = new Random();
int num = r.nextInt(2);
if (num == 0)
    System.out.println("H");
else
    System.out.println("T");
```

`Random#nextInt(int i)` returns a random Integer between `0` and `i-1`

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, although you could implement it easier: `r.nextBoolean();` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need way more inputs in order to get equal number of each. For such small number of outputs sometimes you will get them close to each other in terms of numbers, sometimes one side will "show" way more then other.  Actually, probability of having `4` tails and `16` heads is `0.462%` which is somewhat "realistic" to happen... Try to play with it more with higher number of runs and see how it behaves.

And btw think about this input:

```
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Doesn't seems random, right? But it exist in decimal of number `π` at some point, so its a part of random series. Its just a question of series size, so you must think in that way when you work with random numbers. Think more about random generator rather than about results. You are using correct function since its based on System.nanoTime(), so generator is right, but your result is to small.

Answer (score 0):

> A pseudorandom number generator (PRNG), also known as a deterministic random bit generator (DRBG), is an algorithm for generating a sequence of numbers whose properties approximate the properties of sequences of random numbers.
>
> The PRNG-generated sequence is not truly random, because it is completely determined by a relatively small set of initial values, called the PRNG's seed
>
> Although sequences that are closer to truly random can be generated
>
> Anyone who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin.  John von Neumann